# How to trace process that has already terminated? And even trace back its parent process?

Tags: linux, security, user-management, user-permissions

I am able to jail specific commands execution by a proxy script to a user whose sudo privilege is only this script `sodo` [check here for how to](https://serverfault.com/questions/1136474/is-sudoer-a-must-for-ip-command-anyway-to-get-around-it/1137022). Also the `sodo` script logs whatever critical commands they ordered:

sodo:

```
#!/bin/bash
# pass command by non-sudoers who can only run some command via this script
case $1 in
  firewall-cmd|ip|systemctl)
    #echo $*
    eval $*
    ret=$?
    ;;
  *)
     echo 'your request is not allowed yet, please contact the root user'
     exit 1
     ;;
esac

if [ $ret -eq 0 ];then
  echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %X"`": executed order from" `pwd` "by pid" $$ "to" $* >> /root/sodo.log
fi
```

You might argue the script above does not log the exact user by `$USER` who runs `firewall-cmd|ip|systemctl`. Correct, it is because they run `sodo` as the `root` user, and `$USER=root` so that those 3 would allow them to run given that their sudo privilege does not include the 3.

But here is the loop hole - they can run `sodo` inside a python script inside some public path like `var` and it is impossible to pin down who runs it (who stopped the service maliciously). Now that I have recorded `$$` the pid to run `sodo`, is it possible to trace back the parent pid's back to the login process to pin down who was the actual commander?

---

I figure out a way to trace back its parent user while this script is being processed - since its parent process is not dead yet and `$$` can trace everything about it by `ps` and basic search, it is possible to log the user of its parent process, who was the real commander on this script.

Comment: You seem to be reimplementing `sudo` capabilities in the script. `sudo` can restrict allowed commands on its own and also does log commands in `auth.log`. Also you want to look into `auditd`.

Comment: What could go wrong by passing `ip ; poweroff` as parameters to `eval $*`?

Comment: @A.B it could go wrong, so I log the call in the end, and `poweroff` is not included in the first condition. You could elaborate the conditions by adding more control flow lines.

Comment: The answer: eval will evaluate the command poweroff, while you only checked for the command ip. Never use the eval command provided with untrusted data